# Borda não cobre tudo

Tags: c#, html, css

Minha borda não cobre tudo como gostaria, como podia fazer com que a borda vá ate antes de acabar o `Limite` ?

```css
Meu css:

.conteudo
{
padding: 20px;
}

fieldset
{
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 20px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="conteudo">
       <fieldset>
         <legend>Limite</legend>
       </fieldset>
  </div>
```

O que acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Código todo:

```
@using SoftluxWebCore.ViewModels.Tabelas.Financeiro
<!-- Link to CSS -->
<link href="~/css/Tabelas/Financeiro/FormaPagamento.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

using (Html.DevExtreme().ValidationGroup())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="divFormulario">
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<FormaPagamentoViewModel>()
                                                                .ID("formularioCadastro")
                                                                .ShowValidationSummary(false)
                                                                .Items(items =>
                                                                {
                                                                    items.AddGroup()
                                                                    .Items(groupItems =>
                                                                    {
                                                                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_descricao)
                                                                        .Editor(e => e.TextBox().Width("350px"));
                                                                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_quantidade)
                                                                        .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().Width("70px").OnKeyPress("key_press"));
                                                                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_LimiteDesconto)
                                                                        .Editor(e => e.NumberBox());
                                                                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_acrescimo)
                                                                        .Editor(e => e.NumberBox());
                                                                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_desconto)
                                                                        .Editor(e => e.NumberBox());
                                                                    });
                                                                    items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_situacao)
                                                                        .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
                                                                        .Editor(editor => editor.CheckBox().ID("sit").Text("Ativo"));
                                                                    items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_orcamento).CssClass("orc")
                                                                        .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
                                                                        .Editor(editor => editor.CheckBox().ID("orc").Text("Padrão para Orçamento"));
                                                                })
                                                                .FormData(Model)
        )

    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Limite</legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>


    <br />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sucesso"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Gravar</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-cancelar" onclick="parent.fecharJanela('CadastroFormaPagamento')"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Cancelar</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function key_press(e) {
            var event = e.event,
                str = event.key || String.fromCharCode(event.which);

            if (/^[\.\,e]$/.test(str))
                event.preventDefault();
        }

    </script>
}
}

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Código de criação do modal:

```
function geradorCodigo(idjanela, titulojanela, urljanela, largura, altura, aoFechar) {

    document.getElementById("geradorCodigos").innerHTML = "<div id='" + idjanela + "'></div>";
    var janela = $("#" + idjanela).kendoWindow({
        width: largura,
        height: altura,
        title: titulojanela,
        iframe: true,
        modal: true,
        close: aoFechar,
        content: ".." + urljanela,
    }).data("kendoWindow").open();

    janela.center();

}
```

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir seu erro da imagem. Inclusive editei seu post add o snippet e o mesmo atendeu, qual browser esta testando? pode ser necessário adicionar algum webkit

Comment: Utilizo o google chrome, não sei o que é webkit

Comment: Mas trabalho com janelas, será que pode ser isso?

Comment: Eu reproduzi seu código, ele está correto, veja aqui https://jsfiddle.net/gferreiraa/pu2yos41/

Comment: é possível compartilhar este código da modal todo?

Comment: Vou editar a publicação

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89679/discussion-between-getulio-rafael-ferreira-and-jeff-henrique).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é que em algum lugar do seu CSS ou do Framework que vc está usando existem propriedades na `legend` que não deveriam!

Acredito que dentro da tag `legend` vc pode ter colocado alguma outra tag, ou alguma classe do Framework CSS que está usando. Ou colocou algum elemento de titulo tipo `h3` ou dentro da `legend` e esse `h3` já tinha alguma propriedade CSS nele.

Por algum motivo a sua `legend` deve estar com `width` de `100%`

Veja que desse forma eu simulei exatamente o "erro" que o seu `textfield` apresentou...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima:

```css
.conteudo
{
padding: 20px;
}

fieldset
{
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 20px;
height: 50px;
}

legend {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="conteudo">
       <fieldset>
         <legend>Limite (legend com width de 100%)</legend>
       </fieldset>
  </div>

<div class="conteudo">
       <fieldset>
         <legend style="width: initial;">Limite (legend com width de initial)</legend>
       </fieldset>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sim, o legend recebe width de 100%, já tive um problema com isso q cobria outro objeto, mas não sabia que era por causa disso que a borda n pegava, muito obrigado pela resposta

Comment: E não era css, ele já vem definido por padrão creio eu

Comment: A legend não eh 100% por padrão não ... Em algum lugar tem algum css colocando esse elemento com width de 100%... Tente inspecionar o elemento ai para ver de onde vem a propriedade

Comment: Não tem como enviar imagem aqui, mas creio eu que vem do bootstrap então, http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss, isso que me aparece quando inspeciono e com width: 100%

Comment: @JeffHenrique era isso mesmo, teste aqui no BS3 e BS4 e nos dois o framwrok por padrão coloca a lagend com 100% de width...

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado pela ajuda @hugocsl